# Calculating date in AngularJS. Copying a date value to other variable

Tags: angularjs

I have some trouble with the reference of the date variables.

I have a scope watch like this:

```
    $scope.$watch(
        "vm.firstdate",
        function handleFooChange( newValue, oldValue ) {
            console.log( "vm.firstdate:", newValue );

            //Get create date
            var myCreateDate = vm.firstdate;

            var myDate = myCreateDate ;
            myDate.setHours(myDate.getHours() + 24*(newValue));


            console.log(myDate);

            vm.secondDate = myDate
        }
    );
```

The problem is that the vm.firstdate also change to the value of the second date.
How do I change the vm.secondDate without modifying the vm.firstdate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code.

```
$scope.$watch(
    "vm.firstdate",
    function handleFooChange( newValue, oldValue ) {
        console.log( "vm.firstdate:", newValue );

        //Get create date
        var myDate = angular.copy(vm.firstdate);
        myDate.setHours(myDate.getHours() + 24*(newValue));


        console.log(myDate);

        vm.secondDate = myDate
    }
);
```

The reason why first date is also changing is that the reference pointing to `vm.firstdate` was getting modified and then assigned to `vm.secondDate`. Using `angular.copy(vm.firstdate)` will construct a new instance of `vm.firstdate` & any modifications to this instance won't affect `vm.firstdate`.

Comment: @user3475722 Edited my answer. Please read & accept if the problem is solved.